# Template function taking one or two arguments

Tags: c++, templates

Is there a way to write a function with two templated types;

- taking two arguments, such that
- the second argument is set to a default value if the function is called with only one argument?

The following does not work:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class A, class B>
void f (A a, B b = 0) {
   std::cout << "Hello world!" << std::endl;
}

int main () {
   int i;
   f (i);
}
```

In other words, I would like to have a "template-analogy" to

```
template <class A>
void f (A a, int b = 0) {
   std::cout << "Hello world!" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Well, it doesn't know what type B is, so how can it set a default value for it?

Comment: It could deduce B from the default value. If it did so ... If I call f by `f(i,0)`, then it does.

Comment: If it could deduce the type of B from the default, then why would you make it a template parameter?

Comment: Sometimes I want to write `f(0,"something")`.

Comment: Overload with a `template <class A> void f (A a);`

Answer (score 4):

Yes, if you are prepared to give `B` a default type as well (and use C++11).

```
template <class A, class B = int>
void f (A a, B b = B{}) {
   std::cout << "Hello world!" << std::endl;
}

int main () {
   int i;
   f (i);
}
```

Alternatively overload `f` and provide your defaults as required.

Answer (score 3):

Hope this is what you are looking for, so if f is not passed a second argument then `B` will be an `int` and `b` will be 0. Though that can be changed.

```
#include <iostream>

template <class A, class B = int>
void f (A a, B b = 0) {
   std::cout << "Hello world!" << std::endl;
}

int main () {
   int i = 42;
   f(i);
   f(i, "something");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Overload `f` in such a way that it uses the default value you want:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class A, class B>
void f (A a, B b) {
   std::cout << "Hello world!" << std::endl;
}

template <class A>
void f (A a) {
   f(a, 0);
}

int main () {
   int i;
   f (i);
}
```

You can forward `a` if this implementation is a performance concern.

Comment: I think this is cleanest solution.

Comment: Given the sample code, it would be move, not forward `a`.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the default constructor for the B type.  It will work for primitive data types as well:

```
include <iostream>
include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

class TestClass {
public:
    TestClass() {
        cout << "TestClass()" << endl;
    }
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const TestClass &tcl) {
    os << "TestClass" << endl;
    return os;
}

template <class A, class B>
void f (A a, B b = B()) {
   cout << "Hello world! b=" << b << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    cout << "File: " << __FILE__ << endl;

    f<int, int>(1);
    f<int, char>(1);
    f<int, string>(1);
    f<int, TestClass>(1);

}
```